# the remote host name not resolved with MVC solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am using api.cognitive.microsoft.com to extract text from images
I have the sample code from microsoft web site.

I did make a console project and configure the webApi and every thing is OK and I have the response

But when I make (or call) this code with MVC it don't work (I did make it directly and I did make it in console project and refer it on the MVC project)

The URL :

```
  string uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/ocr";
```

I don't know if it linked to the proxy because when I run it on the console application it's OK.

Any suggestions?

The sample code from this link :

[Sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text)

The error

The remote name could not be resolved: 'westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com'

Comment: can you show your calling code within ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: the same class  sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text

Comment: suspect your request body is not correct...are you sendind image url or raw data?

Comment: I extract this comment to see how the image is sent         // Read the contents of the specified local image
// into a byte array.

// Add the byte array as an octet stream to the request body.

// This example uses the "application/octet-stream" content type.
// The other content types you can use are "application/json"
// and "multipart/form-data".
// Asynchronously call the REST API method.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error? How does it not perform as expected? You need to provide specific details.

Comment: all details are in the question : the sample work on the Console Application and don't work on MVC : error : the remote host name not resolved westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: @Amine That error message needs to be *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my case.
It was about the proxy.
I did add this section to my webConfig:

```
  <system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled="true">
   </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```